# Why i get Null values in my second counter using case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The first case statement i got the correct result but in the second one
Why i got an NULL result Where my second case statement the counter = 2
this is the result i have an image
[Query Result that i got Null data in second statement when i grouped by on my date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CY74.png)

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT date,log,

              CASE
                WHEN note = 'HOLIDAY' AND counter = 1
                THEN 'HOLIDAY'
              END note1,

              CASE
                WHEN note = 'HOLIDAY' AND counter = 2
                THEN 'HOLIDAY'
              END note2,

    FROM  timesheet 
    WHERE timesheet.empid='40' AND date <= CURDATE() AND YEAR(date)= YEAR(CURDATE())
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    GROUP BY date 
    ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: if your 'WHEN note = 'HOLIDAY' AND counter = 2' condition fails it will return null. Can elaborate your requirement?

Comment: simple of . if note have holiday on counter 1 then it will result holiday , and also if note have holiday on the second statement on counter 2 then it will result again holiday on the second column        @TejasVaishnav                                                     ----------------------------------------------------------

Note 1 (Counter = 1)                     Note 2 (Counter = 2)

HOLIDAY                                       HOLIDAY

Comment: you can add  else condition to your case statement to give you desired output in case your condition does not matches

Comment: @Dawn how can i apply that else condition to my case statement can i ask for the simple code for that?

Comment: just add   CASE
                WHEN note = 'HOLIDAY' AND counter = 2
                THEN 'HOLIDAY' Else Value
              END note2,

Comment: thanks @Dawn i got the answer thanks

Comment: @GeorgeMuncal Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You're using `GROUP BY` wrong. The rule is that each column in your `SELECT` clause is either also in your `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function (like count, min, max, avg) must be applied to it.

When you don't follow this rule, a random row for each group is displayed. In your case, when you really have data with `note = 'HOLIDAY' AND counter = 2`, the rows for the group might look like this

```
NULL
HOLIDAY
NULL
NULL
```

but after collapsing (when it's outputted by the select), just the first row is displayed, therefore the NULL value.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT date,
MIN(log), /*or maybe you want to group by this column, too? */

              MAX(CASE
                WHEN note = 'HOLIDAY' AND counter = 1
                THEN 'HOLIDAY'
              END) note1,

              MAX(CASE
                WHEN note = 'HOLIDAY' AND counter = 2
                THEN 'HOLIDAY'
              END) note2,

    FROM  timesheet 
    WHERE timesheet.empid='40' AND date <= CURDATE() AND YEAR(date)= YEAR(CURDATE())
        AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
    GROUP BY date 
    ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Also note, that I removed the `DISTINCT`. Your `GROUP BY` already does that.