# MySQL query error when joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following 3 table:

[image]

And I need to set an HTML table where it displays the following:

```
        <tr class="bg-info">
          <th>Med ID</th>
          <th>Med Name</th>
          <th>Med Expiry</th>
          <th>Barcode</th>
          <th>Number of Tablets received</th>
          <th>Total Number of Pills received</th>
          <th>Date Received</th>
          <th>Pills distributed</th>
          <th>Still (in tablets)</th>
          <th>Still (in pills)</th>
        </tr>
```

So I created this SQL Query:

```
select t1.med_id,
t3.med_name,
t1.med_expiry, 
t1.med_barcode, 
t1.med_tablet, 
t1.med_pill, 
t1.med_received,
sum(t2.given_quantity)
FROM med_pharmacy t1, consultation_med t2, medication t3 WHERE t1.med_pharmacy_id = t2.med_pharmacy_id AND t1.med_id=t3.med_id
AND t1.clinic_id='361'
```

And I received the following error:

> Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1
>   of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'ncd.t1.med_id'; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: And then you get false results. Good job, @UlugToprak

Comment: Read more about [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: So How can I fix it ?

Comment: It is not clear what is your expected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `GROUP BY` wrong. The rule is that each column in your `SELECT` clause is either also in your `GROUP BY` clause or an aggregate function (like count, min, max, avg) must be applied to it.

The sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY prevents that. What happens when you disable it, can be seen in this question: [Why i get Null values in my second counter using case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45097315/447489)

The solution can also be found in the linked question. To repeat it here: apply aggregate functions or include the columns in the group by clause.

You fix it either like this:

```
select t1.med_id,
t3.med_name,
t1.med_expiry, 
t1.med_barcode, 
t1.med_tablet, 
t1.med_pill, 
t1.med_received,
sum(t2.given_quantity)
FROM med_pharmacy t1, consultation_med t2, medication t3 WHERE t1.med_pharmacy_id = t2.med_pharmacy_id AND t1.med_id=t3.med_id
AND t1.clinic_id='361'
group by 
t1.med_id,
t3.med_name,
t1.med_expiry, 
t1.med_barcode, 
t1.med_tablet, 
t1.med_pill, 
t1.med_received
```

or like this

```
select 
MAX(t1.med_id),
MAX(t3.med_name),
MAX(t1.med_expiry), 
MAX(t1.med_barcode), 
MAX(t1.med_tablet), 
MAX(t1.med_pill), 
MAX(t1.med_received),
sum(t2.given_quantity)
FROM med_pharmacy t1, consultation_med t2, medication t3 WHERE t1.med_pharmacy_id = t2.med_pharmacy_id AND t1.med_id=t3.med_id
AND t1.clinic_id='361'
```

or a combination of both, depending on your needs.

When you're using MySQL 5.7 there's also the new function [any_value()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) which you can use instead of an aggregate function. But like the name suggests, it returns any value of the group.

Comment: So how can I fix it ?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Is this new ? I never got this 2 years ago. What does that change means ?

Comment: It is new in version 5.7. What do you mean with "what does that change mean"?

Comment: You didn't have the sql_mode set back then. You can remove it, but if you don't adjust your queries you can get wrong results from your query.

Comment: @droidnation And I meant, that the any_value() function is new, not the sql_mode.